# Detect the shape of a wire

Tags: wire

Is there any electrical or other physical property that can tell me the shape of a wire? I mean, if I inserted a wire into a space (of the same thickness as the wire assume), this property should allow me to detect the shape of the wire, and hence, by extension, the shape of the space it was inserted into.

The "wire" could also be any material or optical fiber cable.

Comment: An arbitrary material, in an arbitrary space? That's pretty broad.

Comment: It sounds like you want to guide a wire through a space and, as the wire bends through the space, you would have some "analysis" of the space that it just entered? That would be a relatively tall order for a simple wire.

And I know you say "any material" but at some point it would be cheaper to x-ray the space you're trying to measure.

Comment: I think the only way to do what you're describing would be to mount a tiny accelerometer on the end of your wire so you can track its movement through the space. I'm not aware of any "wire sized" acclerometers, but the Freescale MMA8652FC is only 2mmx2mm --  I don't know if it has the kind of sensitivity you need.

Comment: @Johnny: If I was to bend this material/wire, there would not be any changes to its physical properties that I could measure? If I reduce the problem speak only of the bend in the wire, is it then possible?

Comment: You can get special resistive sensors which change resistance the more you bend them.

Comment: @pjc50: That is interesting.. can you please point me to a link?

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8606 : note that you get the "total" amount of bend, not the complete shape of the sensor.

Comment: @pjc50: that looks quite good. Why don't you put that as an answer, and I will mark it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resistive sensors will give you a very coarse idea of a shape, by changing their resistance depending on how much they are bent. For example, https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8606

This gives you total curvature, in one dimension.